# Where is this city?

Tags: identify-this

I saw this in the lock screen of Windows, wondering where this is. Any clues?

[image]

Comment: Amazing I was about to post a "where is this Windows lock screen" question!

Comment: It's not specific to your picture, but this might help.
https://superuser.com/questions/1011968/how-do-i-get-more-information-about-windows-spotlight-images

Comment: Also, once you have the image files (as described in my link), you can do a reverse image search on the image.

Comment: Reverse image search is not working, sadly .. Google doesn't know where it is.

Comment: This may help .. https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/location-where-a-spotlight-image-shot/

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of being first to answer, I think it's just So.Cal.

I'd say "Los Angeles from somewhere like Griffith Park".

The hill in front looks wrong but the buildings look correct.

---

## Found it ..

https://www.tineye.com has it where, surprisingly, Google reverse image totally failed.

Unless this photographer bloke is just completely making stuff up, it's a picture by **Carl Larson**

https://www.flickr.com/photos/clarsonx/30493657393/in/photostream/

"Taken on November 7, 2016"

"Another shot of the great sunset from my night at Griffith Park. All the colors in the rainbow!"

Sony ILCE-7R FE70-200mm ƒ/8.0  70.0mm 0.5s  ISO200

(The guy actually gives the full EXIF data there which is neat!)

Comment: It's weird.  SOME of the buildings look correct and some look wrong!

Comment: LA was my first thought too, but there don't seem to be enough skyscrapers.

Comment: This is a photo of LA from Griffith Park
https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/BDObVrteTS2tQ4x4EyfSUxKD1Mg=/0x0:921x615/1200x800/filters:focal(388x235:534x381)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/53711775/Screen_20Shot_202016-10-07_20at_2012.22.59_20PM.0.png

Comment: @Fattie Since the photo appears to be taken looking southwest, the buildings are probably Century City rather than DTLA.

Comment: HI @PeterM !   ?  Prime lenses are *cheaper* than zoom lenses.

Comment: @Fattie I can assure you that I can happily spend more on a single prime lens than zoom lenses if I really wanted to (Hmm that's a nice 800mm Nikkor for $16k).  But in general how many prime lenses are you going to buy in order to duplicate the entire range of a single zoom?

Comment: hi @PeterM !  (1) you were rude, I have no idea why, you don't even know me, can you just delete your comment?  (2) good old prime lenses are the simple, old-fashioned way to do photos; zoom lenses are the "trendy gear snob" approach; so (purely FWIW) your bizarre rude comment ........... made zero sense.  (2)  discussing "lenses" is entirely beyond the remit of this site, so I won't.  Cheers

Comment: I've simply flagged your (bizarre and) rude comment, perhaps please delete it